# Extension Install: TYPO3 12 LTS Extension not visible after install

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

After installing the custom extension for compatibility fix from TYPO3 8 to 12 LTS. The extension is not visible in the backend extensions list.

Comment: How did you install the extension? Via extension manager (old school) or via composer?

Comment: @PeterKraume I installed an extension with Composer mode. Composer installation succeeded without any error or warning. After installation, the extension is not visible in backend extension manager.

Comment: I've the same problem. Installed extension with `composer req sbtheke/cewrap`. Other extensions (e.g. EXT:introduction) shows up, so I assume, something is wrong with my ext.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments of your question you're using composer. Did you make sure that in your `composer.json` the package type is set to `typo3-cms-extension`. See the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/FileStructure/ComposerJson.html) for details.

If you need to change the above mentioned setting I suggest to remove the extension and install it again. After that it might still be necessary to clear all TYPO3 caches.

You should then see your custom extension in `{web-dir}/typo3conf/ext`.

Comment: Thanks,
But as I explained above it's 12LTS and there is no ext folder. And yes the composer JSON file has typo3-cms-extension. my package is inside the vendor folder but missing inside the extension list backend.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.

After correcting some configuration inside the extension composer.json everything works like butter smooth. In extra section it should be defined with extension-key.

```
"extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
        "extension-key": "bloom_contacts"
    }
}
```

Other than that in the old composer the typo3 package was defined like

```
"require": {
   "typo3/cms": "^12.4"
}
```

This will uninstall some of the typo3 packages which required for the system and due to that the application throws several erros.

I corrected this part to the correct package name.

```
"require": {
    "typo3/cms-core": "^12.4"
}
```